# Conditional replace in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
new_df['year'].describe()

count    10866.000000
mean      2004.009939
std         14.958790
min       1968.000000
25%       1996.000000
50%       2006.000000
75%       2012.000000
max       2067.000000
Name: year, dtype: float64
```

It seems like the erroneous year values are +100 years off (ie, 2067 should probably be 1967). Therefore, for values above 2018, how do I [year - 100] while leaving the rest of the values untouched?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
new_df.loc[new_df['year'] > 2018, 'year'] -= 100
```